# Increase value by 1

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am creating a web application with a back-end database. The project is a website that allows user to vote for a team that will win a trophy. The user will have the input a userid, fullname, resident and selected_team which is the team_id.

Once the user information is stored in the database, i want the amount of votes for a certain team to sum up by 1. E.g. A user inputted '2' as a selected team in the 'fan' table. In the 'team' table, the 'votes' column will sum up the amount of '2' from selected team. So 'votes' column will count the amount of '2' in selected_team and place it into 'vote'.

The problem I am having is I'm getting an error which I dont understand how to fix.

```js
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'PK_USER' defined on 'FAN'.
```

The error doesnt occur when I'm adding a new FAN. It doesn't it successfully. However the error occurs when I want to update the TEAM table with relevant information from the FAN table in the JAVA bean.

```js
addEntry = 
           connection.prepareStatement( "UPDATE TEAM SET VOTES = VOTES + 1 "
                 + "WHERE TEAM_ID =" + getTeamID());
         addEntry.executeUpdate(); // insert the entry
```

**SQL Script**

```html
DROP TABLE Fan;
DROP TABLE Player;
DROP TABLE Team;

CREATE TABLE Team
(Team_id INT,
Team_name VARCHAR (20),
Region VARCHAR (10),
League VARCHAR (30),
Manager VARCHAR (20),
Votes INT,
CONSTRAINT PK_Team PRIMARY KEY (Team_id));

CREATE TABLE Player 
(Player_id INT ,
Player_name CHAR (30),
Player_age INT ,
Player_position CHAR (3),
Nationality CHAR (20),
Team_id INT ,
CONSTRAINT PK_Player PRIMARY KEY (Player_id),
CONSTRAINT FK_Player FOREIGN KEY (Team_id) REFERENCES Team (Team_id));

CREATE TABLE Fan
(User_id INT ,
User_name CHAR (20),
Resident CHAR (20),
Selected_team INT,
CONSTRAINT PK_User PRIMARY KEY (User_id));

INSERT INTO Team
VALUES (1, 'Arsenal FC', 'England', 'Barclays Premier League', 'Arsene Wenger', 0);
INSERT INTO Team
VALUES (2, 'Aston Villa FC', 'England', 'Barclays Premier League', 'Tim Sherwood', 0);
INSERT INTO Team
VALUES (3, 'Reading FC', 'England', 'Championship', 'Steve Clark', 0);
INSERT INTO Team 
VALUES (4, 'Liverpool FC', 'England', 'Barclays Premier League', 'Brendan Rodgers', 0); 

INSERT INTO Player
VALUES (1001, 'Wojciech Szczensy', 24, 'GK', 'Poland', 1);
INSERT INTO Player
VALUES (1002, 'Kieran Gibbs', 25, 'DF' , 'England', 1);
INSERT INTO Player
VALUES (1003, 'Per Mertesacker', 30, 'DF', 'Germany', 1);
INSERT INTO Player
VALUES (1004, 'Laurent Koscielny', 29, 'DF', 'France', 1);
INSERT INTO Player
VALUES (1005, 'Tomas Rosicky', 34, 'MF', 'Czech Republic', 1);
INSERT INTO Player
VALUES (1006, 'Mikel Arteta', 32, 'MF', 'Spain', 1);
INSERT INTO Player
VALUES (1007, 'Jack Wilshere', 23, 'MF', 'England', 1);
INSERT INTO Player
VALUES (1008, 'Mesut Ozil', 26, 'MF', 'Germany', 1);
INSERT INTO Player
VALUES (1009, 'Olivier Giroud', 28, 'FW', 'France', 1);
INSERT INTO Player
VALUES (1010, 'Theo Walcott', 25, 'FW', 'England', 1);
INSERT INTO Player
VALUES (1011, 'Alex Oxlade-Chamberlain', 21, 'FW', 'England', 1);
INSERT INTO Player
VALUES (1012, 'Aaron Ramsey', 24, 'MF', 'Wales', 1);
INSERT INTO Player
VALUES (1013, 'Alexis Sanchez', 26, 'FW', 'Chile', 1);
INSERT INTO Player
VALUES (1014, 'Nacho Monreal', 29, 'DF', 'Spain', 1);
INSERT INTO Player
VALUES (1015, 'Santi Cazorla', 30, 'MF', 'Spain', 1);
INSERT INTO Player
VALUES (1016, 'Mathieu Flamini', 31, 'MF', 'France', 1);
INSERT INTO Player
VALUES (1017, 'Calum Chambers', 20, 'DF', 'England', 1);
INSERT INTO Player
VALUES (1018, 'Danny Welbeck', 24, 'FW', 'England', 1);
INSERT INTO Player
VALUES (1019, 'Francis Coquelin', 23, 'MF', 'France', 1);
INSERT INTO Player
VALUES (1020, 'Brad Guzan', 30, 'GK', 'United States', 2);
INSERT INTO Player
VALUES (1021, 'Nathan Baker', 23, 'DF', 'England', 2);
INSERT INTO Player
VALUES (1022, 'Joe Bennett', 24, 'DF', 'England', 2);
INSERT INTO Player
VALUES (1023, 'Ron Vlaar', 30, 'DF', 'Netherlands', 2);
INSERT INTO Player
VALUES (1024, 'Jores Okore', 22, 'DF', 'Denmark', 2);
INSERT INTO Player
VALUES (1025, 'Ciaran Clark', 25, 'DF', 'Ireland', 2);
INSERT INTO Player
VALUES (1026, 'Phillipe Senderos', 30, 'DF', 'Switzerland', 2);
INSERT INTO Player
VALUES (1027, 'Alan Hutton', 30, 'DF', 'Scotland', 2);
INSERT INTO Player
VALUES (1028, 'Aly Cissokho', 27, 'DF', 'France', 2);
INSERT INTO Player
VALUES (1029, 'Matthew Lowton', 25, 'DF', 'England', 2);
INSERT INTO Player
VALUES (1030, 'Leandro Bacuna', 23, 'MF', 'Netherlands', 2);
INSERT INTO Player
VALUES (1031, 'Tom Cleverley', 25, 'MF', 'England', 2);
INSERT INTO Player
VALUES (1032, 'Scott Sinclair', 25, 'MF', 'England', 2);
INSERT INTO Player
VALUES (1033, 'Fabian Delph', 25, 'MF', 'England', 2);
INSERT INTO Player
VALUES (1034, 'Ashley Westwood', 24, 'MF', 'England', 2);
INSERT INTO Player
VALUES (1035, 'Charles Nzogbia', 28, 'MF', 'France', 2);
INSERT INTO Player
VALUES (1036, 'Jack Grealish', 19, 'MF', 'Ireland', 2);
INSERT INTO Player
VALUES (1037, 'Andreas Weimann', 23, 'FW', 'Austria', 2);
INSERT INTO Player
VALUES (1038, 'Gabriel Agbonlahor', 28, 'FW', 'England', 2);
INSERT INTO Player
VALUES (1039, 'Christian Benteke', 24, 'FW', 'Belgium', 2);
INSERT INTO Player 
VALUES (1040, 'Adam Federici', 30, 'GK', 'Australia', 3);
INSERT INTO Player 
VALUES (1041, 'Chris Gunter', 25, 'DF', 'Wales', 3);
INSERT INTO Player 
VALUES (1042, 'Stephen Kelly', 31, 'DF', 'Ireland', 3);
INSERT INTO Player 
VALUES (1043, 'Alex Pearce', 26, 'DF', 'Ireland', 3);
INSERT INTO Player 
VALUES (1044, 'Michael Hector', 22, 'DF', 'England', 3);
INSERT INTO Player 
VALUES (1045, 'Oliver Norwood', 23, 'MF', 'Northern Ireland', 3);
INSERT INTO Player 
VALUES (1046, 'Danny Guthrie', 27, 'MF', 'England', 3);
INSERT INTO Player 
VALUES (1047, 'Hal Robson-Kanu', 25, 'MF', 'Wales', 3);
INSERT INTO Player 
VALUES (1048, 'Jordan Obita', 21, 'MF', 'England', 3);
INSERT INTO Player 
VALUES (1049, 'Garath McCleary', 27, 'MF', 'Jamaica', 3);
INSERT INTO Player 
VALUES (1050, 'Hope Akpan', 23, 'MF', 'Nigeria', 3);
INSERT INTO Player 
VALUES (1051, 'Jem Karacan', 26, 'MF', 'Turkey', 3);
INSERT INTO Player 
VALUES (1052, 'Danny Williams', 26, 'MF', 'USA', 3);
INSERT INTO Player 
VALUES (1053, 'Jake Taylor', 23, 'MF', 'Wales', 3);
INSERT INTO Player 
VALUES (1054, 'Pavel Pogrebnyak', 31, 'FW', 'Russia', 3);
INSERT INTO Player 
VALUES (1055, 'Simon Cox', 27, 'FW', 'Ireland', 3);
INSERT INTO Player 
VALUES (1056, 'Jamie Mackie', 29, 'FW', 'Scotland', 3);
INSERT INTO Player 
VALUES (1057, 'Nick Blackman', 25, 'FW', 'England', 3);
INSERT INTO Player 
VALUES (1058, 'Simon Mignolet', 27, 'GK', 'Belgium', 4);
INSERT INTO Player 
VALUES (1059, 'Glen Johnson', 30, 'DF', 'England', 4);
INSERT INTO Player 
VALUES (1060, 'José Enrique', 29, 'DF', 'Spain', 4);
INSERT INTO Player 
VALUES (1061, 'Kolo Touré', 33, 'DF', 'Ivory Coast', 4);
INSERT INTO Player 
VALUES (1062, 'Dejan Lovren', 25, 'DF', 'Croatia', 4);
INSERT INTO Player 
VALUES (1063, 'Mamadou Sakho', 25, 'DF', 'France', 4);
INSERT INTO Player 
VALUES (1064, 'Martin Skrtel', 30, 'DF', 'Slovakia', 4);
INSERT INTO Player 
VALUES (1065, 'Steven Gerrard', 34, 'MF', 'England', 4);
INSERT INTO Player 
VALUES (1066, 'Philippe Coutinho', 22, 'MF', 'Brazil', 4);
INSERT INTO Player 
VALUES (1067, 'Jordan Henderson', 24, 'MF', 'England', 4);
INSERT INTO Player 
VALUES (1068, 'Adam Lallana', 26, 'MF', 'England', 4);
INSERT INTO Player 
VALUES (1069, 'Emre Can', 21, 'MF', 'Germany', 4);
INSERT INTO Player 
VALUES (1070, 'Joe Allen', 25, 'MF', 'Wales', 4);
INSERT INTO Player 
VALUES (1071, 'Raheem Sterling', 20, 'MF', 'England', 4);
INSERT INTO Player 
VALUES (1072, 'Jordon Ibe', 19, 'MF', 'England', 4);
INSERT INTO Player 
VALUES (1073, 'Rickie Lambert', 33, 'FW', 'England', 4);
INSERT INTO Player 
VALUES (1074, 'Daniel Sturridge', 25, 'FW', 'England', 4);
INSERT INTO Player 
VALUES (1075, 'Fabio Borini', 23, 'FW', 'Italy', 4);
INSERT INTO Player 
VALUES (1076, 'Mario Balotelli', 24, 'FW', 'Italy', 4);
```

JDBC code

```
      // check whether dataSource was injected by the server
      if ( dataSource == null )
         throw new SQLException( "Unable to obtain DataSource" );

      // obtain a connection from the connection pool
      Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();

      // check whether connection was successful
      if ( connection == null )
         throw new SQLException( "Unable to connect to DataSource" );

      try
      {
         // create a PreparedStatement to insert a new address book entry
         PreparedStatement addEntry =
            connection.prepareStatement( "INSERT INTO FAN " +
               "(USER_ID,USER_NAME,RESIDENT,SELECTED_TEAM)" +
               "VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ? )" );

         // specify the PreparedStatement's arguments
         addEntry.setInt( 1, getUserID() );
         addEntry.setString( 2, getUserName() );
         addEntry.setString( 3, getResident() );
         addEntry.setInt( 4, getSelectedTeam() );       

         addEntry.executeUpdate(); // insert the entry

         addEntry = connection.prepareStatement( "UPDATE TEAM SET VOTES = VOTES + 1 "
                 + "WHERE TEAM_ID = " + getTeamID());
         addEntry.executeUpdate(); // insert the entry

         return "Prediction"; // go back to index.xhtml page
      } // end try
      finally
      {
         connection.close(); // return this connection to pool
      } // end finally
   } // end method save

    // return a ResultSet of entries
   public ResultSet getTeams() throws SQLException
   {
      // check whether dataSource was injected by the server
      if ( dataSource == null )
         throw new SQLException( "Unable to obtain DataSource" );

      // obtain a connection from the connection pool
      Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();

      // check whether connection was successful
      if ( connection == null )
         throw new SQLException( "Unable to connect to DataSource" );

      try
      {
         // create a PreparedStatement to insert a new address book entry
         PreparedStatement getTeams = connection.prepareStatement(
            "SELECT TEAM_ID, TEAM_NAME, REGION, LEAGUE, MANAGER, VOTES " + 
                 "FROM TEAM");

         CachedRowSet rowSet = new com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl();
         rowSet.populate( getTeams.executeQuery() );
         return rowSet; 
      } // end try
      finally
      {
         connection.close(); // return this connection to pool
      } // end finally
   } // end method getAddresses
```

Comment: This means you are trying to insert in Fan table, the User_id which already exists there, so there is primary key constraint violation.

Comment: Based on what I can, there is _no way_ that the error you show above is as a result of the following code being executed `connection.prepareStatement( "UPDATE TEAM SET VOTES = VOTES + 1 " + "WHERE TEAM_ID = " + getTeamID()); ` If the stacktrace is leading you believe that this is the line that is giving you the problem, I'd say that you are not running a version of code that is in sync with your source code. Try cleaning the whole project, rebuilding and redeploying

Answer (score 1):

This means you are trying to insert in Fan table, the User_id which already exists there, so there is primary key constraint violation.

Suppose you have in your Fan table the next record:

```
User_id    User_name   Resident   Selected_team

1          "Andrew"    "England"     "Chelsea"
```

If you will try to execute the following query:

```
INSERT INTO Fan(user_id, user_name, resident, selected_team) VALUES (1, 'Dany', 'Ukraine', 'Manchester United');
```

You will get `java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:` because user_id is supposed to be unique (no duplicate values, which help to distinct every row in the table, because you have `CONSTRAINT PK_User PRIMARY KEY (User_id)`) and you now have a record with user_id 1.

Comment: The fan table is able to accept data. I don't have anything wrong the actually store fans. The problem comes up when I'm using this code 
 
addEntry = connection.prepareStatement( "UPDATE TEAM SET VOTES = VOTES + 1 "  + "WHERE TEAM_ID = " + getTeamID());                                                        
                                                               It adds the data into FAN but doesnt update the table TEAM.

Answer (score 1):

When you are trying to insert in to FAN, you are either not setting the user id, or setting it to a value that has already been used by another FAN record in the database.

You have defined the UserID column as a primary key, which means that the values in that column must be unique - a primary key **uniquely** identifies a row in the database.

You don't say what sort of database you are using, but a better strategy for getting these unique id's is to allow the database to allocate them automatically for you. [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) is a mySQL example.

If you take this approach, you don't specify the UserId in the insert statement and just allow the database to handle it for you. If you are able to do this, it is ( in my opinion ) the easiest and safest approach to allocating uniqeue ids to rows.